Securing a Static Content Site with .NET
I've been following the information in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-9.0 to learn about how to secure a part of a static site I'm writing.
The concept is reasonably clear - anything within wwwroot is not secured and will be served according to the app.UseStaticFiles(); middleware.
The secured static content is served from outside the wwwroot folder by the following call.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Secured")),
    RequestPath = "/Private",
});

The crucial point is that this happens after the call to app.UseAuthorization with a default fallback implemented as this:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

This appears to be mostly working, in that when I hit anything under /Private/, the authentication scheme is kicking in.
What I can't figure out is that any resource that doesn't exist (i.e. a 404 ), is resulting in the same fallback, including anything in the root path which I believe shouldn't require any authorization. For example /favicon.ico, or /notapageyet.html will cause a redirect to the "login" page as defined by my authentication scheme.
What have I missed?

After checking the issue, I believe it's middleware issue. (Order otr something).
I create a sample and using below setting, I can access static file resources under wwwroot without authentication, but accessing files under the Secured folder requires authentication.
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Make sure you have UseStaticFiles,
// then you can access the files under wwwroot anonymously
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Make sure below line after app.UseAuthorization();,
// It will allow logged in user can access the files under Secured folder
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Secured")),
    RequestPath = "/Private",
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

